# Using Apps Script to create multiple Forms from a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I would like to use a list in a spreadsheet to create multiple forms for different classes. I have the simple code to build a new form for each class, but I would like to add some form elements to each of the new forms. I know how to build a single form with the elements I want from a script, and I know how to build a bunch of empty forms with a script pulling the form names from the sheet. But I am struggling with the syntax on the forEach section of this script to add the form items to each new form.

```
function createForms() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet5');
  const range = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

  range.forEach(item => FormApp.create(item));
```

This snippet of code creates a new form for each item in sheet 5. Now when this iterates through these new forms, I want to add some items to each form. I am not sure how to get the forEach statement to iterate through the forms and add items to each one.

Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried this but it does not work.

```
function createForms() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet5');
  const range = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  range.forEach(item => FormApp.create(item))
    
    const form = FormApp.create(item);
    form.addTextItem()
    .setTitle('Name')

}
```

After the answer I received (THANK YOU) I have modified the script and it is working to create the forms as shown from the list in the spreadsheet. Lastly, I would like to have the forms created in a parent folder with a new folder for each form.

```
function createForms() {
  
  //use this to force email text box to be email address
  const emailValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText('Input must be email address.')
  .requireTextIsEmail()
  .build();

  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('PUT YOUR FOLDER ID HERE');

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('courses');
  let values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      let form = FormApp.create(values[i]);
      form.addTextItem().setTitle("Name").setHelpText('Please enter your full name').setRequired(true);
      form.addTextItem().setTitle("Email Address").setRequired(true).setValidation(emailValidation).setHelpText('An email address is required');
      form.addParagraphTextItem().setTitle('Details').setHelpText('Please provide the details you need to explain').setRequired(true);
      form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Day Choice").setHelpText('Choose the best day for you').setRequired(true)
      .setChoiceValues(['Monday', 'Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a direct answer as I am only creating one form per spreadsheet but there may be other helpful ideas in my code.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Amy8LgeCdl8RsDr98pEVXVSqrMzGqMc_VuLYQy94mC8/edit?usp=sharing  Make a copy. I am still working on it and will take suggestions or corrections.

Answer (score 0):

#### The main issue here is in the way you are retrieving the list for the form names.

The `getDataRange` method will return the range corresponding to the dimensions in which data is present. However, the `getValues` ends up returning a two-dimensional array of type `[][]`.

While the syntax of the `forEach` is correct, you are essentially only traversing the array in an unidimensional manner.

It is also important to note the fact that when adding an item to a form, you will have to declare the item of the type you want the form element to be.

Therefore, assuming that the spreadsheet looks like the one below and you want each one form to contain 3 elements, this is how the script should look like:

#### Spreadsheet

[image: spreadsheet values]

#### Script

```
function createForms() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet5');
  let values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      let form = FormApp.create(values[i][j]);
      form.addTextItem().setTitle("Text Item " + values[i][j]);
      form.addGridItem().setTitle("Grid Item " + values[i][j]);
      form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Multiple Choice " + values[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note

I suggest you start by using a simple `for` loop if you have doubts related to how the `forEach` works.

However, you can easily switch from `for` to `forEach` in the code above.

#### Reference

- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#getDataRange());
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getValues());
- [create(title)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#create(String)).

Comment: This is working just how I had wanted, I am unsure why we add the 'let j'. I have removed it and it is working just how I like because I have just a single column of course names in the sheet for which I want to create the different forms. The last thing I want to add is to be able to have these forms created in a single folder by id instead of the root of drive, or better yet, in a folder that holds all courses, add a new folder for each new course and put the new form in its own course folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able with the help from ale13 to figure out what I was wanting to do. Here is the final script. It will create a new form, a new folder in the parent folder for each line of data in the sheet that you specify. It is designed for a single column of names, to create a separate form for each class or group and organize them into new folders in a parent folder. The form types and questions can be modified in the script.

```
    /* This script will create a new form for each line in column A of the sheet by name */

function createForms() {
  
  //use this to force email text box to be email address
  const emailValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText('Input must be email address.')
  .requireTextIsEmail()
  .build();

//we will want to save these new forms into a parent google drive folder
//next we will want to create a new folder for each course in this parent folder
// and save the new forms in these child folders with the name of the course

  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('PUT YOUR FOLDER ID HERE');

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PUT YOUR SHEET NAME HERE');
  let values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      let folder = parentFolder.createFolder(values[i]);
      let form = FormApp.create(values[i]);
      form.addTextItem().setTitle("Name").setHelpText('Please enter your full name').setRequired(true);
      form.addTextItem().setTitle("Email Address").setRequired(true).setValidation(emailValidation).setHelpText('An email address is required');
      form.addParagraphTextItem().setTitle('Details').setHelpText('Please provide the details you need to explain').setRequired(true);
      form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Day Choice").setHelpText('Choose the best day for you').setRequired(true)
      .setChoiceValues(['Monday', 'Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday']);
      form.addListItem().setTitle('Rooms').setHelpText('Select your room')
      .setChoiceValues(['Room A','Room B','Room C']);
      let formFile = DriveApp.getFileById(form.getId());
      formFile.moveTo(folder);
  }
}
```